# External Interface in Actionscript 3 does not pass Cyrillic correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, character-encoding, internationalization, externalinterface

I have a flash (flex actionscript project) that has to pass data to javascript in cyrrilic through externalinterface. However, data turns out at the javascript end in ????? instead of real cyrillic letters

how can this be fixed so it shows up as cyrillic?

```
         var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:allInfo('ядене'); void(0);");
         navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

And here is the JS function

```
function allInfo(info){
   alert(info);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably an issue with the encoding at the compilation time. I tested the code you gave and it worked perfectly. Make sure your compiler interpret your file with the proper encoding.

If you want to test it, you can simple do a `trace('ядене')`, if in the console log of Flash, you see wierd character, it's the encoding at compilation time. As to how to fix, I don't know the compiler enough to point you in the right direction.

It could also be a problem with the encoding of the page you are transfering data to. If your Flash file is compiled in UTF-8 and your html page is served with an other encoding that could explain your problem. In that case, just make sure the encoding of the html and your flash file is the same.

In last resort, what you can do to go around most ExternalInterface bug is to `escape` the data on the Flash side and `unescape` it on the Javascript side. Example :

**Flash :**

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:allInfo('" + escape("ядене")  + "'); void(0);");
flash.net.navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

**Javascript :**

```
function allInfo(txt) {
    alert("Test : " + unescape(txt));
}
```

Comment: how would i do that? i am using flex builder 3

Comment: Thanx. Sadly, trace outputs it right. Also, the site itself is well encoded and displays cyrillic by itself. It's just in that transition there....

Comment: @mgPePe It's hard to say at this point what is causing it, ExternalInterface has a couple of bug and it could be not related to your code. In last resort what you can do is `escape` the data before you pass it to Javascript and when you get the data on the other side you can `unescape` it. It's also fixes a couple of issue you can have with ExternalInterface. I added an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me exactly as you have it.  Compiled in Flash Builder 4.5 using the Flex 4.5 SDK targeting Flash Player 11 running in Firefox 4.  Post your test swf and full HTML page if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string to UTF-8 before sending it.

```
// These may seem backwards, just remember it's a conversion situation.
function decode_utf8( s:String ):String {
  return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
}

function encode_utf8( s:String ):String {
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}
```